# Chrome load the same page after I deleted it

Tags: google-chrome, localhost

I have this url: http://localhost:8888/auctions/wins/1

Now I clear all data from chrome (cookies,histori...) and also delete file wins.blade which render the url above but again chrome load the same data...

WHY?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is useless to give us the URL of a local website, because we can't see it.

Second, if you clear your cache and it still displays the same page, then you must delete the wrong file.